# Function reads input and runs function twice

Tags: c++, for-loop, dictionary

I am working on a function in a program to read an input from a user then, the function will check to see if that function exists and then runs it, but it is very buggy and the functions meant to be run, run twice.

```
            //functions with a int and a string
     std::map<std::string, std::function<void(int, string)>> functionsIS = { 
             {"printWordWithNumber", numberPlusWord}, 
     };
     //functions with no parameters
     std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> functionsNI = {
             {"Help", userHelp},
     }; 
void CommandCheck(std::string command){
int paramInt;
string paramString;
for (int i = 0; i < functionsIS.size(); i = i++){
    if (functionsIS[command]){
        std::cout << "Accessed '" << command << "' reading requirements..." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter paramater one (integer) : ";
        std::cin >> paramInt;
        std::cout << std::endl<<"Enter paramater two (string)" << std::endl;
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::getline(std::cin,paramString);
        std::cout << "running..." << std::endl;
        functionsIS[command](paramInt,paramString);
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < functionsNI.size(); i = i++){
    if (functionsNI[command]){
        std::cout << "Accessed '" << command << "' running..." << std::endl;
        functionsNI[command]();
    }
}
}
```

Here is version for you to run:

In source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

#include "userFunctions.h"//header file for functions

using namespace std;

std::string input;
//functions with a int and a string
std::map<std::string, std::function<void(int, string)>> functionsIS = {
    { "printWordWithNumber", numberPlusWord },
};
//functions with no parameters
std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> functionsNI = {
    { "Help", userHelp },
};

void CommandCheck(std::string command){
int paramInt;
string paramString;
for (int i = 0; i < functionsIS.size(); i = i++){
    if (functionsIS[command]){
        std::cout << "Accessed '" << command << "' reading requirements..." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter paramater one (integer) : ";
        std::cin >> paramInt;
        std::cout << std::endl << "Enter paramater two (string)" << std::endl;
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::getline(std::cin, paramString);
        std::cout << "running..." << std::endl;
        functionsIS[command](paramInt, paramString);
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < functionsNI.size(); i = i++){
    if (functionsNI[command]){
        std::cout << "Accessed '" << command << "' running..." << std::endl;
        functionsNI[command]();
    }
}
}

int main(){
do{
    std::cout << "Waiting For Command..." << std::endl;
    cin >> input;
    CommandCheck(input);
} while (input != "end");


return 0;
}
```

Create a header file called "functions" and paste this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void numberPlusWord(int number, std::string word){
std::cout << word << std::endl;
std::cout << number << std::endl;
}

void userHelp(){
std::cout << "I can help!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please **edit** your post and include an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: **Never do `i = i++`**. It must be `i++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code that would cause problems. The first is that you are iterationg through the function map and if the command exists you are calling it. The problem is that you are checking for the same command on every iteration so if the map contains more than one element the command will be called for each of them. You can resolve this by removing the `for` loop and using the `find` function of the map to determine if the command exists.

The second problem is that if the command does not exist an element will be created in the map for it. The `if` statement below will automatically insert an element using `command` as the key.

```
 if(functionsIS[command]) { /*...*/}
```

The following update to your code will correct the problem.

```
void CommandCheck(std::string command)
{
    int paramInt;
    string paramString;

    if (functionsIS.find(command) != functionsIS.end())
    {
        std::cout << "Accessed '" << command << "' reading requirements..." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter paramater one (integer) : ";
        std::cin >> paramInt;
        std::cout << std::endl << "Enter paramater two (string)" << std::endl;
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::getline(std::cin, paramString);
        std::cout << "running..." << std::endl;
        functionsIS[command](paramInt, paramString);
    }
    else if (functionsNI.find(command) != functionsNI.end())
    {
        std::cout << "Accessed '" << command << "' running..." << std::endl;
        functionsNI[command]();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, it works great now; I am not very familiar with maps and their functions so I did not really know about '.find()'